# I have difficulty to construct x path for below code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have difficulty to construct x path for below code:

```
<div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options"><input type="select-one" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="srclang-selectized" placeholder="Type source language *" style="width: 151.109px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;"></div>

<select name="srclang" id="srclang" data-placeholder="Type source language *" class="form-control1 selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"><option value="" selected="selected"></option></select>
```

May I know How to construct x path for this?

Comment: <input type="select-one" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="srclang-selectized" placeholder="Type source language *" style="width: 151.109px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;">

Comment: Hello @Anand, what element do you want to select ?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more of the HTML surrounding this element, also what have you tried already? Is there any reason you're unable to select it from just the id which should be unique?

Comment: Select SourceLanguageIs= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='srclang-selectized']")));
        SourceLanguageIs.selectByIndex(2);
        //SourceLanguageIs.selectByVisibleText("English");
       // SourceLanguageIs.selectByValue("90");

Comment: Unable to  select the language from drop down.
Select SourceLanguageIs= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='srclang-selectized']"))); SourceLanguageIs.selectByIndex(2); //SourceLanguageIs.selectByVisibleText("English"); // SourceLanguageIs.selectByValue("90");

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try below xpath. I am sure it's gonna work.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id="srclang-selectized"]"));

Please do let me know your response on the same.

Comment: Anand - Did you get a chance to validate it?

Comment: Hi Using the above code drop down is click but unable to select the source language from the drop down.

Comment: Hi @Anand you only requested to construct the xpath.Anyways, I have written the code snippet to click on drop-down and select a value. Kindly have a look. Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("srclang-selectized")));
dropdown.selectByIndex(-1);

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below xpath(if you're not been able to select the element by using the id):

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder,'Type source language')]"))`